# overlay single image over a gridview array

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, overlay

i've created a gridview that's populated with an array of images right now it has 9 images but planning on making larger.  i'm trying to set it up so when i click on an image it will overlay that image with a single image (a red x) i've found several examples of overlaying images on top of a gridview but they all seem to use another array. i tried setting my single image up as an array but that doesnt seem to work. i have the onitemclicklistner also working and i can make the image show up for the first image. was thinking of trying to fill the entire grid with the x and have it hidden (not sure if that's the best way or not)

right now it's not working because i'm trying to add the second image.

my grid adapter

```
public class EasyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private int[] easyPics;
private int[] overlayPics; //used for overlay ...this is just created here

Context myContext;

public EasyGridAdapter(Context myContext, int easyPics[], int overlayPics[]){
    //sets gridadapter to use pics , if had text under pic would need to add after int[] pics
    // name EasyGridAdapter is name ot the java class
    this.myContext = myContext;
    this.easyPics = easyPics;
    this.overlayPics = overlayPics;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return easyPics.length;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return easyPics[position];

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid = convertView;
    if (convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //not sure what for
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_easy, null);

    }
    //main view
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.ivPics); //ivPics is android id name of imageviewer in custom easy xml
    ImageView ol = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.overlayImage);

    iv.setImageResource(easyPics[position]); //easypics is the interger from above
    ol.setImageResource(overlayPics[position]);



    return grid;  //returns grid which is name of grid on activity_main.xml (with all stuff in it)
}



   **my custom xml file**

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPics"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/e1"
    />

 <!--added to overlay image when item clicked.-->
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlayImage"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/x"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

**part of my main activity let me know if you need to see more**

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnEasy:

            creatArray();
            btnEasy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //hides button on the second activity
            btnMed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnHard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        //  EasyGridAdapter adapter = new EasyGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, easyArray);
            EasyGridAdapter adapter = new EasyGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, randomPics, overlay); //have to add all images (arrays here)

            grid.setAdapter(adapter);

        //listens for click on grid
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             //sets what to do if each grid is pressed
                    if(position == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked 1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      // shows that was clicked. shows x
                     //   ImageView overlay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.overlay);
                      //  overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    if(position == 1){

                        ImageView overlayImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.overlayImage);
                        overlayImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if(position == 2){

                        ImageView overlay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.overlayImage);
                        overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

edited custom xml

```
public class EasyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private int[] easyPics;
private int[] overlayPic; //used for overlay ...this is just created here

Context myContext;

public EasyGridAdapter(Context myContext, int easyPics[], int overlayPic []){
    //sets gridadapter to use pics , if had text under pic would need to add after int[] pics
    // name EasyGridAdapter is name ot the java class
    this.myContext = myContext;
    this.easyPics = easyPics;
    this.overlayPic = overlayPic;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return easyPics.length;
   // return overlayPic.length;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
   // return easyPics[position]; //wored with just easypics
    return position;

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid = convertView;
    if (convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //not sure what for
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_easy, null);

    }
    //main view
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.easyPics); //EasyPics is android id name of imageviewer in custom easy xml
    ImageView ol = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.overlayPic);

    iv.setImageResource(easyPics[position]); //easypics is the interger from above
    ol.setImageResource(overlayPic[position]);



    return grid;  //returns grid which is name of grid on activity_main.xml (with all stuff in it)
}
```

Comment: why don't you add the overlay image in the xml file as hidden and then show the image `onClick` ?

Comment: i tried adding it to my custom_xml file and in my MainActivity.xml file as a hidden image and then onClick showing it.  but it only shows up in the top of my layout it doesn't matter which image i click on its always in the same spot.

Comment: You have to use custom layout for gridview. I can show if you like.

Comment: Sorry I had to run to a meeting ..But I have one custom layout already do I add to that one or create a second one? I think most of my custom layout is posted above. Thanks

Comment: sorry. im back ok. i'm attemping to add my overlay image in to my custom.xml file. i will post the edited code back in the original question.  but it is crashing when it tries to load now.

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. :)

Comment: ok  I found the problem but i'm not sure how to fix it now. this line of code (the full code is above)  ol.setImageResource(overlayPic[position]); is breaking it. if i replace [positon] with [0] it doesn't crash but it will still only show the overlay image in the top left.  is this due to the fact that i'm trying to use a single image for the entire grid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141457/discussion-between-tahsinrupam-and-branedge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Remove/Comment** `onItemClickListener` from your `GridView`:

2) I am assuming you are using a `RelativeLayout` as parent of `custom_easy.xml` . **Modify** `getView()` method as below:

```
 public class Holder
{
RelativeLayout rlParent;
ImageView iv;
ImageView ivOverlay;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid = convertView;
    final Holder holder=new Holder();
    if (convertView == null){    
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //not sure what for
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_easy, null);

    }
    //main view
    holder.rlParent = (RelativeLayout) grid.findViewById(R.id.yourParentLayout);
    holder.iv = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.ivPics);  //ivPics is android id name of imageviewer in custom easy xml
    holder.ol = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.overlayImage);

    holder.iv.setImageResource(easyPics[position]); //easypics is the interger from above
    holder.relParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.ol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });   

    return grid;  //returns grid which is name of grid on activity_main.xml (with all stuff in it)
}
```

Hope this helps.